# SQL Alchemy not creating db

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm following a CRUD tutorial using Flask and SQL Alchemy.

In the tutorial, when he runs this code, it's created a folder called 'instance' and inside it there's the .db file.

When I do the same, the folder is created but not the file. I checked over and over this code, and it matches with his, so I couldn't find a reason why it's not working.

```py
#Imports 
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_scss import Scss
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
import os 

#App
app = Flask(__name__)
Scss(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] ='sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#Data Class
class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(length=100), 
    nullable=False)
    complete = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Task {self.id}"


#Routes
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


#Runner
if __name__ in "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it myself on windows and it runs flawlessly. And since it can create the folder I'm guessing it's either a problem with permissions to create a .db file:

- On Linux do `chmod -R 777 app_directory_name`
- On Windows try making it somewhere like documents folder

or something with the relative path:
try including this line in `app.app_context()`

```
if __name__ in "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        print(db.engines)
```

and check if the printed path is correct

If neither work try creating a fresh virtual environment (`python -m venv venv`) or trying on a different OS.